# Pushing to dokku from Gitlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci

I want to automate my NodeJS application deployment. I am using **Gitlab** and **dokku** , both is on digitalOcean. How to make this happen that whenever i push on gitlab, the code will automatically pushed to dokku ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used  [Gitlab CI](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html) .Go through its documentation, its easy.